# Parse JSON and add markers to google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

i am trying to parse some JSON data and then transform it into google map markers, but the problem is that I still getting this error:

unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

```
    function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-35.889050,-64.735108);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    var jsonArch = '{ "codigo" : "3127" , "nombre" : "name" , "zona" : "3127" , "geoX" : "-58.443597" , "geoY" : "-34.807164" },{ "codigo" : "3128" , "nombre" : "name" , "zona" : "3128" , "geoX" : "-58.488797" , "geoY" : "-34.576852" },{ "codigo" : "3124" , "nombre" : "name" , "zona" : "3124" , "geoX" : "00.000000" , "geoY" : "00.000000" }';

    var archiJASON = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonArch);
    /*jQuery.parseJSON(jsonArch, function(json1) {*/
        jQuery.each( archiJASON, function(key, data) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data.geoX), parseFloat(data.geoY)); 
            // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: data.nombre
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
        });
    /*});*/

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The map is visible, but I could not load markers...

This is JSON data:

```
'{ "codigo" : "3127" , "nombre" : "name" , "zona" : "3127" , "geoX" : "-58.443597" , "geoY" : "-34.807164" },{ "codigo" : "3128" , "nombre" : "name" , "zona" : "3128" , "geoX" : "-58.488797" , "geoY" : "-34.576852" },{ "codigo" : "3124" , "nombre" : "name" , "zona" : "3124" , "geoX" : "00.000000" , "geoY" : "00.000000" }'
```

Thank you very much, any help would be appreciated, this really matters me.

Comment: Why are you creating JSON markup and then parsing it all in the same function? In any case, your JSON isn't valid. You're creating a list of objects, but you didn't put them in an array structure. Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON.

Comment: Because JSON is generated at server side, using google Gson, from sql query. Then I extract some objects to test without running the server.

Comment: Then the problem to fix is the server-side code that's making the invalid JSON.

Comment: how do you know that this JSON is invalid? why? Because I validated it in some online validators, and it says it is valid. That is why I can not understand errors

Comment: If you used a JSON validator that told you it's valid, then stop using that validator. Again, you have a list of object structures, but left out the list (array) syntax. `[{"codigo" : "3127", "no...}, {...}, {...}]`

Comment: So, you mean that correct json data would be something like this: [{"codigo" : "3127" , "nombre" : "name" , "zona" : "3127" , "geoX" : "-58.443597" , "geoY" : "-34.807164"}, { "codigo" : "3128" , "nombre" : "name" , "zona" : "3128" , "geoX" : "-58.488797" , "geoY" : "-34.576852" }, { "codigo" : "3124" , "nombre" : "name" , "zona" : "3124" , "geoX" : "00.000000" , "geoY" : "00.000000" }] . The error dissapears, but map is blank, what is going on?